# Pinescript - I'm plotting 2 chars (using plotchar()) on an oscillator type indicator- How do I maintain their position relative to one another?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I'm using plotchar() to draw characters onto an oscillator type indicator. I need these characters to maintain their position relative to one another when the user scales the indicator vertically. I've signed an NDA, so I'm trying to ask the question without giving any details away. There are 4 total - 2 for bullish signals, and 2 for bearish. I've plotted them in the exact same way, and the bullish ones seem to maintain their relative position, but the bearish ones don't?

I used the plotchar() function and specified the position of each character as an integer value - e.g -85 and -88 for the bullish ones, 85 and 88 for the bearish ones, using location.absolute. I want the characters to print one top of each other without overlapping. When the user scales the indicator vertically, the realtive position of the 1 pair seems to change, whereas the other pair stays constant. I'm a junior, new to pinescript, and I feel like there's something obvious I'm just not seeing? I've tried using location.top and location.bottom but that makes the chars overlap.

Comment: Could you be so glad and provide feedback to the answers? That's how Stackoverflow lives

Answer (score 0):

you did not show any script, so this is the generic way to do it

```
plotchar(bull1? -85:na,char="1",location=location.absolute)
plotchar(bull2? -88:na,char="2",location=location.absolute)
```

Comment: Thanks so much, but that's basically exactly how I've already done it. I can't share the code because of my NDA. I Was hoping there'd be some other way?

Comment: try the same with plotshape() that is best i can do without seeing some script

Answer (score 0):

Yeah... that's indeed a lack of functionality. Here's a little "Hack". This solution uses dynamic a vertical offset between each icon, based on he current price behaviour. It's a more or less acceptable solution, considered that something like that is actually not possible out of the box.

```
condition1 = true // actually calculate ...
condition1Index = 1
condition2 = true // actually calculate ...
condition2Index = condition1 ? condition1Index + 1 : condition1Index
offset = ta.atr(1)
plotchar(condition1 ? high + offset * condition1Index : na, char='1', location=location.absolute)
plotchar(condition2 ? high + offset * condition2Index : na, char='2', location=location.absolute)
```